# Search a Word in a 2D characters array

Tags: c, arrays

Given a 2D array of size 100 x100  of characters and a word (1D character array), find the occurrences of given word in 2D array (search only left to right horizontally).

```
char data[100][100] =
{
    "ACFRTBOOK",
    "BOPNBOOKQUIZGEEK",
    "IDEQAPRACTICE"
};
char  Word[4] = "BOOK";
```

Output:

```
pattern found at 0, 5
pattern found at 1, 4
```

Comment: This is clearly an assignment. SO users can help you in understanding what's wrong with your attempt, but cannot do the assignment for you.

Comment: As @RobertoCaboni said, we won't do the assignment for you. But you could start by going through the rows until you find the first letter, and then try to find out if what follows equals the word that you are searching. Give it a try, and let us know if you have any problem.

Comment: Your initialization helps -- you have more than just an array of characters, you have 3 nul-terminated strings in `data` -- but not in `Word`. You can use your strings to your advantage by iterating over each until a nul-character is found checking if they contain the characters in `Word` in sequence... Post what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: It's not an assignment, it's an extra question that the doctor gave us to practice on but I don't really know from where to start, and it's my first time learning c that's why so if someone would like to help me write this code or understand it he/she can do

Comment: Hint: start searching the character `B`, that is the first element of the `word` array. Ps: shouldn't the line `char  Word[4] = "BOOK";` raise a warning?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni why should it raise a warning?

Comment: plus should I do a loop to search for all the letters? I'm really bad at this if someone can help, I'm trying to learn but its somehow difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
int k = 0, n = 0;
char word[] = "BOOK";

for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; data[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        n = j;

        while (data[i][n] == word[k] && word[k] != '\0')
        {
            n++;
            k++;

            if (word[k] == '\0')
            {
                printf("Found at %i, %i", i, j)
            }
        }

        k = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, but in the first loop what do you mean by i<size, what is the size or the size if what?

Comment: The number of rows in your matrix

Comment: thank you so much for your help, do you recommend me any websites or youtube channels to learn c from, because I'm really struggling

Comment: From my experience, the best way to learn C/C++ is just by coding and using a good textbook. You can also use http://www.cplusplus.com/, but be careful, as it is a C++ reference, although you can find some C help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot initialize a char array as a String like you did with `char Word[4] = "BOOK";` this would have to be `char word[4] = {'b','o','o','k'};` The same applies to your 2D array named data.

So here is how you would do such a thing. I added in //comments to explain, but the general idea is to turn the arrays into Strings as these are easier to use when locating another set of characters.

Please let me know if you need further assistance. I hope this helps.

```
public void findWord(char[] word; char[][] data){
    String w = new String(word); //it is much easier to work with strings for a searching problem like this
    int x=0,y=0;
    for(char[] i:data){//iterates through each row of data
        String d = new String(i);
        while(d.contains(w)){
            x+=i.indexOf(w);//locates the pattern
            System.out.println("pattern found at " + x + ", " + y);
            x++;
            d=s.substring(x);//this removes the previous occurance of the patern so that the index of can find a new repeat in the same row 
        }
        y++;
        x=0;//reset for next array
    }
}
```

Comment: He's asking for C help. Java might confuse him

Comment: thank you, yes I'm asking for help in c, plus I'm a girl

Comment: Oh, bold assumption there. I'm so sorry :(

Comment: It's okay ❤️❤️❤️

Comment: @Adrisui3 Thanks for pointing that out lol, I thought I was viewing the java tag but apparently not.

Comment: @Rama Sorry, I thought I was viewing the java tag but apparently not. I am not very good at c so I can't help you with this one.

Comment: its okay thanks anyways